# IPC for "waking up" from epoll() (C, UNIX)

Tags: c, unix

I need to "wake up" a process that is waiting on epoll() **from another process**.

I've created a UDS (AF_UNIX) type SOCK_DGRAM where:

- The client every few ms **might** send one char to the server
- The server is waiting with epoll() on the socket for read

  - I don't need the data from the client, only to "wake up" from it

How can i do this the **most efficiently**? 
Do i have to read() the data?
Can the server somehow ignore the data without overloading the socket's memory?

Comment: Get something to work first. Then determine if it is efficient enough.

Comment: No code == WAG answers.

Comment: the `epoll()` exits when any of the sockets it is monitoring shows data available.  Usually that is followed by a `read()` from the socket with data.   Then your code can do what every is desired, then return to the `epoll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i have to read() the data? Can the server somehow ignore the data without overloading the socket's memory?

If you're receiving data on a socket on an ongoing basis then yes, you need to read that data, else the socket buffer will eventually fill.  After it does, you will not receive any more data.  You don't need to do anything with the data you read, and you can consume many bytes at a time if you wish, but reading the data is how you remove them from the socket buffer.

You will also find that `epoll_wait()` does not behave as you want if you do not read the data.  If you are watching the socket fd in level-triggered mode, and there are already data available to read, then `epoll_wait()` will not block.  If you are watching the socket fd in edge-triggered mode, and there are already data ready to read, then receiving more data will not cause `epoll_wait()` to *un*block.

> How can i do this the **most efficiently**?

Are you really worried about single-byte `read()` calls at rate not exceeding one every few milliseconds?  Is this for some low-power embedded system?

I don't really see a lot of room for improvement if you've settled on using epoll for this.  If it turns out not to perform well enough for you, then you could consider alternatives such as process-shared semaphores or signals, though it is by no means clear that either of these would be superior.  This is what performance testing is for.